# Matlab gui-Fill an array by checking multiple checkboxes

Tags: arrays, matlab, user-interface, checkbox

I have a gui, that has 6 checkboxes. If the user doesn't choose any checkbox a message is displayed.But if a checkbox is choosed an array takes a specific number. If the checkbox one is choosed, the array box=zeros(6,1) must became box(1,1)=1 leading to an array 
box=[1 0 0 0 0 0].

The problem is when i choose more than one checkboxes.The array box takes only the last checkbox number that is choosed. The code that i use for every checkbox is:

```
checkbox1_Callback(hObject, ~, handles)
isChecked = get(hObject,'Value');

if isChecked==1
        box(i,1)=i;%% i=1:6
        handles.box=box;
end
guidata(hObject, handles)  %% that code is for every checkbox
```

at the end when a button is pushed the array box is passed to the workspace.

```
function Button_Callback(hObject, ~, handles)

if nnz(handles.box)==0
    handles.message=msgbox('Please select ...');
else
    assignin('base', 'box', handles.box);
guidata(hObject, handles)
```

So how do i have a an array that takes alla the values,all the checkboxes that are choosed, and not the last one that is choosed??

Thanks for any response.

Comment: What is `i` there? How do you vary that `i`?

Comment: { i  } is not in the code. I put 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 dependding at the number of the checkbox.

Comment: Are you using `box = handles.box` at the start of each callback and then doing - `if isChecked =..`? If not, that might be the issue.

Comment: Thanx a lot!That was the case.